# Using survfit function on Byar Dataset

Tags: r

I have to plot distribution function for 2 causes of deaths of Byar Dataset. In Byar dataset of clustMD, events range from 1 to 8, for several causes of death.I am using the following code:

```
library(clustMD)
data(Byar)
A<-Byar

library(survival)
attach(A)
time<-Observation
event<-SurvStat

B<-survfit(Surv(time,event)~1, data=A)
plot(B,xlab="Time",ylab="Survival Probability")
```

This gives me a curve, but it is not corresponding to two causes of deaths. Would
'survfit(Surv(time,event=="1"|event=="2"|event=="3")~1,data=A)'[Plot obtained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQuLe.png) give me plot for 2 causes of death, where event=1 is alive, and other two are causes of deaths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that there are more than 2 or 3 levels in SurvStat. If multiple levels describe the same cause of death then it needs to be recoded.

```
pacman::p_load(clustMD)
data(Byar)
A<-Byar

library(survival)
attach(Byar)
time<-Observation
event<-SurvStat

B<-survfit(Surv(Observation,event=SurvStat, type="mstate")~1, data=Byar)
plot(B,xlab="Time",ylab="Survival Probability")
```

Comment: Different values of events, corresponds to different cause of death, and there are total 7 different causes of deaths, event=0 means alive, and others for different causes of death.

Comment: @PiyushChittara Great. I was just pointing that out because your question mentioned something about 2 causes of death. It sounds like this answers the question then. If you found the answer helpful please feel free to mark it as the solution. By the way, if you meant that you're only interested in the first 3 factor levels of SurvStat then the only change you need to make is to drop the rows with unnecessary levels or recode them to an NA / other level.

Comment: so, after doing that.. it will show event took place if event=1 or 2, and no event took place if event=0 ? .. since that's what i will need for survival analysis.

Comment: @PiyushChittara Almost. The only catch is that with `mstate` you may need to recode the event variable by one level because the first level indicates censoring. But asides from that, yes, that's how `mstate` works and it's what you use for multiple causes of death. The plot from this code has one line for each cause of death. To quote the documentation: "For multi-state survival (type= "mstate") the status variable can have multiple levels. The first of these will stand for censoring, and the others for various event types, e.g., causes of death."